# BeanUtils throwing NullPointerException in hashCode()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using the `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean` to copy properties between objects. But it's throwing `NullPointerException` exception in `hashCode()` method. When I check the `DB`, `prodcode` property is not `null`. So shouldn't throw `NullPointerException`.

My `DTO` `object` is like below.  One notable thing is, I store same `EquipmentDTO` as child equipments into this equipment. All the equipment has same property. So I use recursive pattern.

eg. One parent equipment can have many child equipment.

```
public interface Copiable {
     public Object copy();
}



public class EquipmentDTO implements Copiable {
    private Long equipid;
    private String prodcode;
    private List<EquipmentDTO > childEquipmentList;  // Recursively store child Equipment

    public EquipmentDTO () {
       super();
    }

    public Long getEquipmentid() {
       return equipid;
    }

    public void setEquipmentid(Long equipid) {
       this.equipid= equipid;
    }

    public String getProdcode() {
       return prodcode;
    }  
    public int hashCode() {
       return getProdcode().hashCode();
    }

        @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
       if(o == null)return false;

       if(!(o instanceof EquipmentDTO ) ) return false;

       EquipmentDTO other = (EquipmentDTO ) o;

       return this.prodcode.equals(other.getProdcode());

    } 
}
```

The `NullPointerException` occurs only in production environment.
I use Java 1.6, Oracle weblogic.

## Update

`BeanUtils` code snipt.

```
public static void copy(Object src, Object dest) {
     try {
        org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean beanUtil = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance();
        beanUtil.getConvertUtils().register(false, true, 0);
        beanUtil.copyProperties(dest, src);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
        //set dest to null if exception
        ite.printStackTrace();
        dest = null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        //set dest to null if exception
        iae.printStackTrace();
        dest = null;
    }
}
```

## Update

Here is the stack trace.

```
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.vo.EquipmentDTO.hashCode(EquipmentDTO.java:361)
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:219)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties(BeanUtilsBean.java:246)
```

Comment: The value in your database is irrelevant if it's not being loaded into your object. What's the value of `prodCode` on the instance of your class that's being used? (Also, it's generally appreciated if the code in your question would actually compile.)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist   The value is loading. The value is loaded to the another object which has same properties. I need to copy from that object to this `EquipmentDTO ` object. To copy, I use `beanutils`.  The value is a string like `12564850N`

Comment: Please provide the code that uses `BeanUtilsBean` to copy the properties.

Comment: @hzpz    Updated the `BeanUtils` usage

Comment: @everalian Could you also provide the stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: @hzpz  the NPE is return in the `getProdcode().hashCode()` in `EquipmentDTO` class.

Comment: Yes, you already stated that in your question. The stack trace however will tell you, who calls `hashCode()` in the first place. Another note: the code you gave doesn't even compile because there is a getter called `getProductcode()` but in `hashCode()` you use `getProdcode()`. Generally, BeanUtils expects objects to conform to the JavaBean specification, i.e. getters and setters have to be named like the field.

Comment: @hzpz   Actually this code is modified with different names. Apology for my typo. Unfortunately I do not have the stacktrace now as I added a null check to `getProductcode()`  inside the `hashCode()` like this. `  if (null != getProductcode()) {                
                return getProductcode().hashCode();
            }` Otherwise I cannot fix this issue.

Comment: It's unlikely that we can help you without an exception stack trace.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BeanUtils, but it's obvious that `prodcode` is null when `hashCode()` is called. Debugger could give you more information.

Answer (score 4):

You have an exception, because you are copying to an empty `dest` bean which has the `null` value in the `prodcode` field. This way `dest.hashCode()` throws an exception and as the consequence, the `dest.toString()` (which uses default implementation of `Object.toString()` which calls the hash code) also throws a `NullPointerException`. The `toString()` method is called by [`BeanUtilsBean`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.java/#245) to make the debug output:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("BeanUtils.copyProperties(" + dest + ", " +
              orig + ")");
}
```

So here `dest` is converted to string causing the `NullPointerException`.

In general in Java it's always presumed that for published objects `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()` never throw an exception. So it's better to fix the `hashCode()` implementation using:

```
String prodcode = getProdcode();
return prodcode == null ? 0 : prodcode.hashCode();
```

Or if you can use Java-7:

```
return Objects.hashCode(getProdcode());
```

Comment: I know this happens because prodcode has null values. But in my DB, prodcode is not null. All the objects has the value. So this is my problem, How come it become null. Also the system is working in UAT environment. Only production environment this issue comes in.

Comment: @everalian, is it not null for both `src` and `dest` objects? How do you create the `dest` object? The difference is likely in logger configuration. If debug logging is disabled, then this code is not executed, so you will get no NPE.

Comment: The `dest` is obviously an empty object. The data is copy from `src` to `dest`. I did not debug as you mentioned. But when I query the data in DB, all the records has `prodcode`. So `src` object cannot have `null` value in `prodcode`.

Comment: @everalian, but `dest` do have empty prodcode. The `dest` is causing NPE, not `src`.

Comment: But how come this code work before? also this one working fine in `UAT` environment?

Comment: @everalian, as I said before, it's likely that logging configuration was changed. Check your `lcf` or other logging configuration file.

Comment: I implement Logback and enabled debug in this release. So then that cause the error? But I still wonder why it's not happen in `UAT`?

Comment: @everalian, I don't know. I can't see your code. This draws us too much away from the original question. Ask another question about logging and include all the relevant code snippets.